# I need to find two letters in this circle

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

I found a circle with some letters *(the letters are in order)* but two of them are not legible.
**Who can help me finding the lost letters?** (not necessarily English)

[image]

Clue:

> Language: Spanish

Comment: Interesting, minimalistic puzzle. Is a specific language required? If you don't want to tell, that's fine, but then everybody will assume English (if any) language is needed.

Comment: Is it U and I which forms CIRCULO ?

Comment: to the downvoter, I'm new in this site, if you can tell me why you vote down, I can improve my next question, thanks

Comment: @user2408578 can be other too

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer If specifying the language makes the puzzle too easy, it will be enough to specify it is *not* (necessarily) English. But it is up to you. (And you can deleted comments.) BTW, I did UV not DV. ;c)

Comment: I've edited the title. Please check if this was against your intentions.

Comment: its not single word isn't it ?

Comment: This does look kind of too broad... I could invent reasons why almost any pair of letters could be inserted. I think you need to add more detail to the question. (But I didn't DV either!) BTW, do you know the answer or are you asking for help?

Comment: According to http://www.crosswordsolver.org/ there's no English word that fits.

Comment: @randal'thor I know the answer, what kind of detail you need? And what is the meaning of DV and UV?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer UV = Upvote, DV = Downvote.

Comment: I think they could be the initials of items belonging to a set of 7 (like colours), but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: It *was* meant to be English, then you can only match words if the letters don't have to be in order. Colcord, Caloric, Caracol, Chloric, Clocher, Clocker, Cockler, Coracle, Carlock, Ceclors.

Comment: @leoll2 spent some time I can give more clues?

Comment: @randal'thor I edit with this text *the letters are in order*

Comment: Maybe it is in cuban / spanish / mexican?

Comment: @Daedric Cuban and Mexican are not languages, Spanish yes ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer well actually each country has different variations of Spanish which is considered the countries language (the variation): e.g: in Cuba they speak Cuban Spanish in Spain they speak Spanish and in Mexico they speak Mexican Spanish. So technically they are different languages, and I simple said is it Cuban / Spanish / or Mexican rather than writing Cuban Spanish etc.. you of all people should know they are different. Also you didn't answer my question!

Comment: @Daedric IMO, If the word was in variation of language I think it would be very difficult to decipher. I get your point

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer not necessarily in English means it could be in any language with an English alphabet so I saw you lived / worked in Cuba and I put 2 and 2 together, all you have to say is "yes it is", or "no it isn't", or even "I don't want to tell you".

Comment: @Daedric thanks for the explanation, you have one possible answer?

Comment: No but here is a question (again): I don't speak Spanish, can I still answer the puzzl3?

Comment: @Daedric yes, is simple

Comment: answer may be C & F?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati no

Comment: @user2408578 you get the answer, post it and you can explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i am posting my answer removing from comment

It is

> U and I  which forms the word CIRCULO (Spanish)

Comment: I might add that you could also use "I" and "O", as in CIRCOLO (italian), but given the OP's name I guess spanish is more correct

Comment: I found a circle ... then circle in spanish is CIRCULO ;-)